# Is there a way to replay the tutorial in Plants vs Zombies 2?

Tags: android, plants-vs-zombies-2

I didn't get the achievement for playing the tutorial, because I didn't sign in the first time I played.

Is resetting my progress the only way to do it?

I'm trying to get all the achievements, but this one eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There currently is no way to re-do the PvZ 2 tutorial.**

But, since your trying to get the `Off The Green-Achievement` all you have to do is:

1. Create a new account (located at the start-up page of PvZ 2)
2. Go through the tutorial and finish the fourth level.
3. Profit! The achievement will be game-wide, so you should get it on your main!